# Spyder installed via Anaconda not working once I install pyinstaller

Tags: anaconda, pyinstaller, spyder

I am trying to use pyinstaller with python that I installed via Anaconda.  I also use Spyder that installed with Anaconda.  If I install Anacoda without installing pyinstaller, then Spyder works, if I install pyinstaller, then Spyder stops working or in some instances when using pyinstaller, it complains that it cannot find the PyQt5 plugins.  I have tried everything and also searched on google, but cannot find a solution that resolves this issue.  It is on my work laptop, which still uses Windows 7.  Does someone perhaps know how to resolve this?

I searched on google for potential solutions and tried some suggestions, nothing works.

Comment: I don't think this is possible because probably PyInstaller is pulling `pyqt5`, which is incompatible with the PyQt packages provided by Anaconda, sorry.

Comment: Is there something else that can be used to make .exe files, which works with Spyder?

Comment: Instead of using Anaconda, you should use a regular Python installation. That should work, but I don't know for sure.